# Prism MVVM ObservesCanExecute - How Do I Nest (Logical AND Over) Simple Observable Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm fairly new to Prism, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to leverage the `ObservesCanExecute` (which allows me to not have to manually ask the command to re-calculate) for use with multiple properties. With a single property, this works like a charm! But I want to perform an "and" across all of my three properties.

Here is the code:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(MyCommandHandler)
                .ObservesCanExecute(() => BoolOne)
                .ObservesCanExecute(() => BoolTwo)
                .ObservesCanExecute(() => BoolThree);
}
private bool _boolOne;
public bool BoolOne
{
    get => _boolOne;
    set => SetProperty(ref _boolOne, value);
}
...
```

What I'm experiencing is that once `BoolThree` is set to true, the button (attached to this command) is enabled without checking `BoolOne` and `BoolTwo`. How can I get this to also act like the command predicate is `return BoolOne && BoolTwo && BoolThree`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use ObservesProperty here instead of ObservesCanExecute. https://prismlibrary.com/docs/commanding.html

> Do not attempt to chain-register ObservesCanExecute methods. Only one property can be observed for the CanExcute delegate.
>
> You can chain-register multiple properties for observation when using the ObservesProperty method. Example: ObservesProperty(() => IsEnabled).ObservesProperty(() => CanSave).

So you will want to change your code to this:

```
MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(MyCommandHandler, MyCanExecuteMethod)
            .ObservesProperty(() => BoolOne)
            .ObservesProperty(() => BoolTwo)
            .ObservesProperty(() => BoolThree);

private void MyCanExecuteMethod()
{
    return BoolOne && BoolTwo && BoolThree;
}
```

This way when any of those properties change the RaiseCanExecuteChanged will be fired.

Comment: That works. Though I was thinking I could get away without a "CanExecute" separately defined. Thank you - I'll use this for now!

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer from Big Hats is completely correct, I would like to show another variant here that I personally like better:

```
MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(MyCommandHandler, () => BoolOne && BoolTwo && BoolThree)
            .ObservesProperty(() => BoolOne)
            .ObservesProperty(() => BoolTwo)
            .ObservesProperty(() => BoolThree);
```